# Mark as Duplicates bug

Tags: bug

Is it appropriate to report a bug here? If not I will close this question.

I was trying to mark

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217742/python-pycrypto-error-runtimeerror-autoconf-error-and-failed-building-wheel-for

as a duplicate of

[pycrypto on Ubuntu giving compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625352/pycrypto-on-ubuntu-giving-compiler-error) . But when I click on the button a new window opens and takes me to

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/115083/open-source-developer-open-edx-python-django-opencraft?med=clc&ref=large-sidebar-single-blue

without the question being marked as duplicate. This might be my dream job but at the moment I am more concerned with marking this question as duplicate.

Chrome 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) Linux Mint

Update: I just tried to mark as 'too broad' on another question with the same result. Also at the time of writing the other question does not have any answer let alone an upvoted answer.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, in my case the vote to close button is fully visible and not hidden by anything else. Yet when the vote to close button is clicked on it leads to the ad being opened in a new tab

Comment: In both of them the close vote is clearly visible, and in both of them clicking that close button results in the job ad opening in a new browser tab. It's the same issue with the job ad receiving the click events intended for the question close vote button.

Comment: @KenWhite ok, time to delete :)

Comment: Oh hang on a second that one doesn't have ny answers yet

Comment: No, don't delete it. If people see it, they'll also learn of the post it duplicates, which will get the attention to it.

Comment: The other post has an answer now (which is that the bug has been fixed).